# Issue with MPI_Irecv

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I'm writing a simple MPI program that allows a process to send a random number to the next rank and also receive the random number of the next rank using non-blocking communication.

For example:

```
Process 0 sends 1 to process 1
Process 1 received 1 from Process 0
Process 1 sends 3 to process 0
Process 0 received 3 from Process 1
```

I tried:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "mpi.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rank,size; //rank and size of the process.
    int value; //the random value generated.

    int nreq;
    int buf[1]; //receiving buffer

    MPI_Init(&argc,&argv); //initialize MPI environment

    MPI_Request req[2];
    MPI_Status stat[2];

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank); //processes rank
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&size); //total size of process

    if (rank < 2) { //if process rank is less than 2, means we want those to generate random numbers.
        nreq = 0;
        srand(time(NULL)+rank); //seed for the random number generator.
        value = rand() % 10; //generate the random number based of the seed value
        //printf("Process of rank %d generated the value 
          //%d\n",rank,value);

      MPI_Isend(&value,1,MPI_INT,rank+1,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);
      printf("Node %d sent %d to node %d\n",rank,value,rank+1);

     MPI_Irecv(&buf[0],1,MPI_INT,rank+1,1,MPI_COMM_WORLD,&req[nreq++]);
     printf("Node %d received %d from node %d\n",rank+1,buf[0],rank);

     MPI_Waitall(nreq,req,stat);
 }

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}

but I'm getting the error saying

```
mpirun detected that one or more processes exited with non-zero status,thus causing the job to be terminated.
```

Comment: how many MPI tasks do you run ? note your `printf()` are misleading. A node has not received a message until `MPI_Wait()` says so. For example rank `0` expect a message from `1`, but `1` only sends to `2`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I'll run 2 task for this example.so the feasible way is to add the printf statement after the MPI_Waitall? So in this case, printf is allowed after MPI_Isend but not MPI_Irecv?

Comment: I am afraid you are missing the main point. If you run 2 tasks, then task `1` currently communicates with task `2`, which is an invalid rank, and hence your error. If you run more, then task `0` (at least) will wait forever

Comment: also note `MPI_Sendrecv()` can do `MPI_Isend()`+`MPI_Irecv()`+`MPI_Waitall()` all at once

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thanks but there's something I'd like to confirm. For the case of Irecv, the first parameter where &buf[0] literally means that the value it received is added into the buf array that i initialized? Is that how it works?

Comment: since `count=1`, it means that the message to be received will be available at `but[0]`

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet if a rank sends a value to the right process, denoted by rank +1 and the left process denoted by rank-1, am i allowed to have the same tag during the Isend/Irecv for both directions or must they be different?

Comment: the tag used by the left process in `MPI_Send()` must be identical to the tag used by the right process in `MPI_Recv()`, no more, no less. The answer to your question is they can be identical (and imho, making them not identical would be quite a mess to handle)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet thank you! One last question, I've been going through some examples online and i realized that in MPI_Irecv() the first buffer parameter doesnt require the '&' followed by the buffer array name in their example but for my example, it requires the '&' sign followed by buf which leads to '&buf[0]'. etc else i would get an error. Why is that so?

Comment: If you declare `int *buf` or `int buf[1]`, then you can either use `but` of `&buf[0]` as the buffer argument. If you declare `int value`, then the buffer argument has to be `&value`. If you still have an error, then ask a new question and include a [MCVE]